# Load another XHTML into the center layout, but the application not responding after three updates

Tags: ajax, jsf, include, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces layout in my template.xhtml file, and in my index.xhtml I try to include a page dynamically into the center layout as I navigate in a tree. It works well but after the fourth click in the tree, the application isn't responding anymore. It updates the center page three times and after the fourth click it freezes.

Here is a part of my template.xhtml:

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
    <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="50">
        <ui:insert name="header"></ui:insert>
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="65" resizable="true" collapsible="true"> 
        <ui:insert name="footer"></ui:insert>
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="west"  size="250" header="TreeMenu" resizable="true" collapsible="true"> 
        <ui:insert name="treemenu"></ui:insert>
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

Here is a part of my index.xhtml:

```
    <ui:define name="treemenu">
        <p:tree id="tree1" dynamic="true" value="#{treebuilder.tree}" var="node" selectionMode="single" selection="#{treebuilder.selectedNode}">
            <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{treebuilder.onNodeSelection}" update=":contentpanel"></p:ajax>
            <p:treeNode>
                <h:outputText value="#{node.trzKod}"></h:outputText>
            </p:treeNode>
        </p:tree>
    </ui:define>    
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:panelGroup id="contentpanel" layout="block">
            <ui:include src="#{treebuilder.centerPage}"></ui:include>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </ui:define>
```

I think that the problem is somewhere in the ajax update, but I don't know what did I wrong.

Comment: Where is the form that is supposed to surround `tree1`?  I believe that the ajax call will attempt to update form elements if it is surrounded by one and I don't believe that having a form outside of a `layout` will work.

Comment: There is no form that surrounds tree1. I tried to surround it but nothing changed. The ajax call updates the panelgroup three times, and after that the page not responding to anything.

Comment: That is an oddly specific number.  Can you confirm that a postback is occurring to the server?  Are there any error logs on the server after the third click?  Where there any validation errors?

Comment: There isn't any errorlog on the server, there is no validation error. It seems that after the third click, the select event not fired. In the browser after the third click the fourt selected element in the tree is highlighted, but the onNodeSelection event not fired.

Comment: It could possibly be a Javascript error occurring.

Comment: If I delete the <ui:include tag from the panelGroup, then the select event fired well for every selection, so I think updating the include tag causes the problem.